# How to make a responsive modal? CSS

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I got an assignment to make a modal below responsive. Should I just place more media queries or fix modal sizes to a percent? Are there any techniques,tips or websites which could help me to accomplish my goal?

Thank you in advance.

Modal Parent:

```
.OverlayModal {
  z-index: 2;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Modal:

```
.SignInModal {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    margin: auto;
    width: 238px;
    height: 550px;
    outline: none;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 0;
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        width: 420px;
        height: 400px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy solution is to give `width` a percentage value like `width:50%` then add `min-width` to avoid overshrinking and `max-width` for overexpanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple,

**Percentage based layout** is used when the layout should be similar on every screen.

**Media queries** is used when you want to change the layout on different screen sizes.